# Affected rows from seesion logs does not reflect in actual target table in Informatica

Tags: postgresql, informatica-powercenter

I have a simple mapping loading source to target (Postgres table), on running the session when I check 'Get Run Properties' I can see a certain number of rows affected, but in reality, there is no load happening at the Target table.

With the same session and the same target table in earlier runs, the data would get loaded.

What could be possible reasons for this?

Thanks in advance for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

There can be a number of reasons. Basically the Affected Rows tell you how many rows Informatica sent to DB. Yet in DB there can be triggers, that take actions on the sent rows yelding different result. Or there can be indexes that prevent duplicates from being created, without giving an error.

Also, check your target settings - perhaps these are updates, not inserts?

Please also check PostSQL property in the session - I've seen a case where PostSQL contained a procedure completely overwritting the mapping logic.

Answer (score 0):

The possible reasons could be,

- Issue in the format of the data, a date or an integer column would have incorrect format
- Unique indexed on the target table

Did you check the session log, you would find the errors in case of data format issue

Comment: Yes, checked the session log!. 
There is a  Lookup transformation (On target table) used right before loading data to target table, here the primary key for target table is determined by 'Sequence-ID' property in Associated Expression tab in lookup.
Error I could see is - violation of primary key constraint on target table, but the value lookup is taking as primary-id for target table is not 'already present' in actual when checked from database! 
So why would it say that it is already present and reject the record when inserting!

Comment: Then looks like, it is trying insert duplicate records